# Is is possible to define the height of a UITableView's tableHeaderView purely based on Auto layout?

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

It seems that the size of a `tableHeaderView` has a constant height even when auto-layout is enabled for the storyboard.  I can define it's subview's sizes with auto-layout but not the view its self.

Using either code or interface builder, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can't set header height with AutoLayout but with code
try setting the frame property of the tableHeaderView.

```
UITableView *tableView;
CGRect frame = tableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
frame.size.height = 200;
tableView.tableHeaderView.frame = frame;
```